# How I can get Images in PDF with ITEXT and convert PDXObjectImage format to BufferedImage

Tags: java, pdf, itext, barcode

I need to get the images in one specific page inside the PDF, but I need to convert this image the format of ITEXT PDXObjectImage to BufferedImage, is possible?, How I can?.

I saw several examples with extraction, but I need to get in memory not in file, because I want to use with ZXING Library to read a Barcode.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: `PDXObjectImage` is Apache PDFBox, not iText. However, see this [official example from iText](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=283) which shows how to get a `PdfImageObject` and then calls `getImageAsBytes()` on that object. Once you've got raw bytes you should be [able to get a `BufferedImage` from that](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-byte-to-bufferedimage-in-java/).

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry, I try to use your solution and works for PDFBOX but I have another problem, because this BufferedImage is use to process with ZXING library to read a QR Barcode, I don't know if the problem come from PDFBOX or this library, anyway I just open another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143728/itext-error-with-zxing-library-reading-qr-barcodes-in-pdf to talk about that, thanks for your help.