# Error with ZXING library reading QR Barcodes in PDF

Tags: java, itext, zxing

I'm using ZXING Library, with this code I can get the images in my PDF, concretly QR Barcodes, but when I try to get the information inside ZXING library... I can't find the Barcodes.

But if I take the same barcode from the file like `barocode.png`, works perfectly.

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Workarea\\testBarcode.png"));

buffered = (BufferedImage) image;
```

How I can fix that? is internal error of the library ZXING? I have to use another implementation?

I was testing with PDFBOX too, and I had the same error.

Anyone can help me?

```
public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {

    BufferedImage buffered = null;          

    try {
        PdfImageObject image1 = renderInfo.getImage();

        LuminanceSource source;

        byte [] imageInByte = image1.getImageAsBytes();

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);

        source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bImageFromConvert);

        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

        Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);

        ParsedResult parsedResult = ResultParser.parseResult(result);

        System.out.println(" (format: " + result.getBarcodeFormat() + ", type: " +
        parsedResult.getType() + "):\nRaw result:\n" + result.getText() + "\nParsed result:\n" +
        parsedResult.getDisplayResult());
        System.out.println("Found " + result.getResultPoints().length + " result points.");

        for (int i = 0; i < result.getResultPoints().length; i++) {
            ResultPoint rp = result.getResultPoints()[i];
            if (rp != null) {
                System.out.println(" Point " + i + ": (" + rp.getX() + ',' + rp.getY() + ')');
            }
        }
    } catch (NotFoundException ignored) {
        System.out.println("No barcode found!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code is inspecting bitmap images in the PDF for barcodes. Are you sure the barcode is in such a bitmap? It could just as well be drawn using vector graphics or written using some barcode font. If you are not sure, please supply a sample PDF for inspection.

Comment: I discovered that I have only the error when I use my pdf, if I use another images works, checking the problem, I saw that my BufferedImage have #pixelBits = 8 when works, and 1 when doesn't work, now the question is How I can fix that without change the original, because I can't. some idea?

Comment: I had a error with the type of the Barcode, is not a QR is a Data MAtrix ECC200, but the only way to read the content is with one image bigger and a white border surround the Data Matrix